# Should unit tests be sample-dependent

Tags: java, unit-testing

I am creating a unit test for an entity, let's say MyEntity.
In order to test, I am using samples of this entity, created in the test.
I know that tests must be independent from each other.
What about the sample objects created for this purpose.
Should a test be also independent from the samples it uses?

Let me give you an example:

```
public class MyEntity {
  private List<OtherEntity> otherEntities = new ArrayList<>();
  ...
}

public class MyEntityServiceTest {
  private MyEntity myEntitySample;
  private OtherEntity otherEntitySample;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    otherEntitySample = new OtherEntity();
    otherEntitySample.setId(22);
    myEntitySample = new MyEntity();
    myEntitySample.setId(11);
    myEntitySample.addOtherEntity(otherEntitySample);
  }

  @Test
  public void findByOtherEntityId() {
    MyEntity myEntityResult = myEntityService.findByOtherEntityId(otherEntitySample.getId());
    assertEquals(myEntityResult.getOtherEntities().get(0).getId(), otherEntitySample.getId());
  }
}
```

In this example I test the behavior that the found MyEntity object's first OtherEntity item has indeed the same id (22) as the object being searched with. Which is correct in my case, because the sample I am using actually has only one OtherEntity object as a property.

So, my test passes when using these samples. If I were to change my samples and use a MyEntity object which would contain the same OtherEntity object but as a second item in the otherEntities list, then the test would have failed, even though it shouldn't.

**Should I leave it as it is, or should I change it so that it tests the general behaviour of the method?**

I hope this doesn't get too confusing.

Comment: I don't get why the test would fail in that case, if you are querying like you are: myEntityService.findByOtherEntityId(otherEntitySample.getId()); then it should return always the proper otherEntity with id 22, shouldnt?

Comment: This looks to be a general discussion question about writing tests. Please try to ask a more specific question, or post on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In breif, tests should be written to be indepndant of each other, and never include shared mutable state or side effects

Comment: @Fernando - The method would work correctly. The assertion would fail if I set the second item to have the id 22, because it expects the first item (get(0)) to have this id.

Comment: What @Brad said is correct, but I don't think that being violated in your code. The Before methods occurs before every unit test, and the test is not changing the status, so no cross dependency between tests or order of tests execution are introduced.